# What is #syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental?

Tags: dockerfile

I have been working with dockerfiles for a while now but today I was working on a small project and somehow on my VScode I typed # then CTRL+SPACE on the first line I got this `syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental`.

I don't understand what this does and can't find documentation about it can somebody explain what's with that weird comment.

> PS I found some people using this so it's not just some random comment generated by vscode I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a way to enable new syntax in Dockerfiles when building with BuildKit. It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#overriding-default-frontends):

> ## Overriding default frontends
>
> The new syntax features in Dockerfile are available if you override the default frontend. To override the default frontend, set the first line of the Dockerfile as a comment with a specific frontend image:
>
> ```
> # syntax=<frontend image>, e.g. # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
> ```
>
> The examples on this page use features that are available in docker/dockerfile version 1.2.0 and up. We recommend using docker/dockerfile:1, which always points to the latest release of the version 1 syntax. BuildKit automatically checks for updates of the syntax before building, making sure you are using the most current version. Learn more about the syntax directive in the Dockerfile reference.

I have used it to enable SSH Auth Sock forwarding.

Comment: So what will be the default frontend version I will be having with my docker setup. Is there any command by which I can know it from the terminal ? I am not sure if I need to update it or not.

Comment: Is it possible to define a specific image as default in daemon.json ?

Comment: New location of documentation: https://docs.docker.com/build/dockerfile/frontend/